# Triple with ISO8601 date breaks RDFJSON parser in dotnetrdf

Tags: c#, json, parsing, rdf, dotnetrdf

I am trying to parse an RDF/JSON graph with help of dotnetrdf and it fails when I have a date as literal, below is some sample code with the problematic triple that causes the problem.

```
 using VDS.RDF;
 using VDS.RDF.Parsing;
 ...
 var jsonstr = @"
 {
  ""http://example.com"": {
    ""http://purl.org/dc/terms/issued"": [{
        ""datatype"": ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date"",
        ""type"": ""literal"",
        ""value"": ""2017-10-24T15:01:53+02:00""
      }]
    }
  }";

  IGraph g = new Graph();
  g.LoadFromString(str1, new RdfJsonParser());
```

Causes the following execption:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfParseException
Exception thrown: 'VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfParseException' in dotNetRDF.dll: '[Line 4 Column 40 to Line 7 Column 44] Unexpected Token 'Date' encountered, expected a Property Value describing one of the properties of an Object Node'
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfJsonParser.Error(JsonParserContext context, String message, PositionInfo startPos)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfJsonParser.ParseObject(JsonParserContext context, INode subj, INode pred)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfJsonParser.ParseObjectList(JsonParserContext context, INode subj, INode pred)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfJsonParser.ParsePredicateObjectList(JsonParserContext context, INode subj)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfJsonParser.ParseTriples(JsonParserContext context)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfJsonParser.ParseGraphObject(JsonParserContext context)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfJsonParser.Parse(IRdfHandler handler, TextReader input)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfJsonParser.Load(IRdfHandler handler, TextReader input)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.StringParser.Parse(IGraph g, String data, IRdfReader reader)
```

The problem is the same if I remove the explicit datatype. But the problem dissapers if I change the literal so it is no longer a combined date and time expression according to ISO8601. E.g. having only the date works.
This feels like a bug, or is it a configuration issue?

My package references are:

```
<PackageReference Include="dotnetrdf" Version="1.0.12" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="VDS.Common" Version="1.8.0" />
```

My guess is that the underlying JSON parser (Newtonsoft) tries to be smart and detects the string to be something it can translate into a date object. As I am a beginner in c#, my debugging skills are somewhat shaky so I am stuck at guessing.

Any form of guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Json.Net doesn't "try to be smart". That's the expected behaviour. .NET devs would revolt if it didn't work this way. If you don't want to parse a field, you can tell it to read the field as a string, use an attribute on the target class, or [change the default serialization settings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm) and set [JsonSerializerSettings.DateParseHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateParseHandling.htm) to [None](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is correct - the Newtonsoft parser is helpfully converting the ISO date format into a Date object. It is functionality of the Newtonsoft parser that can be disabled and our RdfJsonParser should probably disable it because we don't want the string converted to a Date object.

Unfortunately I don't think that there is a way that you can do this from your code - it is a fix that is needed in dotNetRDF itself. I've logged this as [issue #130](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/issues/130) on the dotNetRDF issue tracker.

Edit: This should now be fixed in 2.0.0-pre0009

Comment: Looks like all that's needed is to set `DateParseHandling= DateParseHandling.None` in CommentIgnoringJsonTextReader's constructors ? There doesn't seem to be a way to inject a configured reader or any other setting to `RdfJsonParser`